# BVHTree.FromPolygons not accepting vertex list

Tags: python

I'm having an issue using BVHTree.FromPolygons. It doesn't appear to be accepting my vertex list.

Documentation of the function: [BVHTree.FromPolygons](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_9/mathutils.bvhtree.html#mathutils.bvhtree.BVHTree.FromPolygons)

Example:

```
import bpy
from mathutils import *
from mathutils.bvhtree import BVHTree

# This one doesn't work
verts = [Vector((0,0,0)), Vector((0,0,1)), Vector((0,1,1)), Vector((0,1,0))]

# Neither does this one
verts2 = [(0,0,0), (0,0,1), (0,1,1), (0,1,0)]

# Gives "TypeError: BVHTree.FromPolygons"
print (BVHTree.FromPolygons(verts, [0,1,2,3]))
```

It gives this very vague error message in the console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\planefromnormal.blend\Text.001", line 9, in <module>
TypeError: BVHTree.FromPolygons
Error: Python script fail, look in the console for now...
```

Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The second argument is a sequence of polygons, try BVHTree.FromPolygons( verts2, **[** (0,1,2,3) **]** )

Comment: Well now I look stupid haha, yep that did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops, it wasn't the verts that was the problem. It was the polygons sequence. It requires a sequence of sequences:

```
BVHTree.FromPolygons( verts2, [ (0,1,2,3) ] )
```

Thanks lemon for the answer!